# How to iterate a CSV and do calculations with it

Tags: python, csv, python-3.4

Edition:

I am trying to iterate a CSV file of a company to do some calculations of stock prices, but can't seem to get it. Let's say I have this CSV file:

`List.csv`:

```
Date,Quantity,Price
20150101,2,1
20150102,10,3
20150103,4,2
20150104,5,4
```

And I want to be able to do such calculations as:

```
(pseudo-code)
if List [2] [2] < List [1] [2]:
# to check if 20150103's Price (2) is smaller than 20150102's Price (3)
```

and if so, then...

```
Total = List [2] [2] * List [1] [2]
# which is 2 * 3 = 6, or any other calculation as necessary
```

And of course there will be iteration from List [0] to List [-1].

How can I do such iteration and calculation?

(Sorry for the confusion. This is my very first time coding and using this public service, so some unintended mistakes in conveying my problem.)

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing here. What is the actual problem that needs solving? Are you trying to *exclude* rows that have the 3rd value smaller than the preceding row?

Comment: I got this file of a company's historical stock price data and I want to code the moving average of the company's historical price. So while I can do a csv.reader and print the iteration, I don't know how to calculate the data in each row. If only I can take the data of, say row[1], that is row[1][4] (for example), and multiply it with the data of row[2][4] (for example). And yes, I will need to iterate the whole file, from row[0][4] to row[-1][4].

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to want to **iterate** as you say, since you're doing computations using different rows and indeed in your pseudocode you're calling the data `List`, implying it's all in memory at the same time.

That's OK, as long as the CSV file isn't just too huge to fit.  I also see that some columns are strings, some are integers, so you'll need that indication somewhere, such as a tuple of types:

```
types = int, None, int, int
```

corresponding to each column, with `None` meaning "leave it alone" (as a list).

So, given this...:

```
import csv

thelist = []
with open('the.csv', 'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for fields in r:
        sublist = [f if t is None else t(f)
                   for t, f in zip(types, fields)]
        thelist.append(sublist)
```

Now in `thelist` you have all values with the proper types, so your desired computations translate easily:

```
if thelist[2][2] < thelist[1][2]:
    total = thelist[2][3] * thelist[1][3]
```

Now in a comment you insist you *do* want to iterate, in which case the above indecing makes little sense and it becomes totally non-obvious what `total` should be kept and where as the iteration proceeds.

So you should really clarify your pseudocode to express what you actually **want**, since the pseudocode currently in your Q cannot possibly express that.  Maybe you want to do your computation, not on `thelist[2]` and `thelist[1]`, but "current sublist" and "previous sublist", and put the totals that are computed in a list, not in a scalar where each new computation overwrites the previous one (just a guess at your secret intentions, since I'm not good at mind-reading).  In that case I might restructure the code as:

```
import csv

types = int, None, int, int

def fields2sublist(fields):
    return [f if t is None else t(f)
            for t, f in zip(types, fields)]

totals = []

with open('the.csv', 'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    previous = fields2sublist(next(r))
    for fields in r:
        current = fields2sublist(fields)
        if current[2] < previous[2]:
            totals.append(current[3] * previous[3])
        previous = current
```

or the like.  Clarify your **actual** intentions, and either kind of code can probably be tweaked to fit; or, choose to leave them mysterious, but then don't expect much help.

Note that the widespread worry about reading a whole file in memory is usually misplaced; few applications actually need to ingest gigabytes to do their work (it happens -- just far more rarely than people realize).

So while it's important to know how to iterate, for the sake of the rare cases where gigabytes actually impend, in real-life programs it's usually OK to ingest the input in one big gulp at the start, then iterate on **that** list.  You do need to know your application's exact operating parameters to make that decision, of course.

Comment: The calculation will be used to iterate the entire csv file.

Comment: But if the file is huge, you want to avoid this altogether. It is trivial to track the preceding row and base conditions on that as you iterate.

Comment: Moreover, it is simply not clear what the OP is trying to achieve here. Presumably the OP wants `total` to involve more than just those two specific rows, for example.

Comment: @Dorky, so this latest comment shows you printing all fields, which has nothing to do with the original Q.  Why don't you read my answer and, if needed, edit your Q to specify (pseudocode is fine by me) exactly **what** you want to do?  In my A I took a guess, but nobody's a mind-reader here -- it's **your** responsibility to actually formulate a fully understandable question!

Comment: @Alex, Yes, I still need to iterate. The total will be appended to a separate list with updates as the total changes with each iteration. The code is to iterate and calculate the data of a stock (as in stock market), like trying to calculate the moving average, thus the calculation that will iterate. And yes, the file is huge. Nevertheless, a simply how-to on doing it at the basic level would be sufficient, I guess.

Comment: @Dorky, looks to me like my long, detailed answer meets your somewhat-but-not really explained specs, including the "total appended to the separate list" part (no idea what "updates" and "each iteration" you mean as you never specify more than one iteration or what could change between them).  So I think my answer *does* give you "a simple how-to" -- as much as possible for the Q as it stands (or even with further minor edits).  So **try** this code (adapted for your newly altered example CSV, of course) and either accept it or edit your Q to show what *exactly* it isn't doing that you need.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the csv file is not too big, you can try:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> list=pe.load("list.csv", name_columns_by_row=0)
>>> list.column.format('Price', int)
>>> list[2,2] * list[1,2]
6
```

It's possible to turn the following statement:

```
Total = List [2] [2] * List [1] [2]
```

into an intuitive one:

```
Total = List ['20150103', 'Price'] * List ['20150103', 'Price']
```

by writing one more line of code:

```
>>> list.name_rows_by_column(0)
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> list['20150103', 'Price'] * list['20150102', 'Price']
6
```

More documentation can be found [at read the docs](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/v0.1.2/tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I am not trying to use Python with Excel, but just Python alone. I am trying to do with Python on what can be done with Excel, but so far a bit disappointed.